# How to convert accented string to unaccented string in english in python without converting any other language character?

Tags: python, string, unicode, non-ascii-characters, accent-sensitive

What I want is to convert accented characters into english and if there is some other language present then it should give blank.I have tried certain codes like below but its converting even the other langagues to english below or removing them.What should I do?

```
def check1(email):
try:
    email = unicode(email, 'utf-8')
except (TypeError, NameError): # unicode is a default on python 3 
    pass
email = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', email)
email = email.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
email = email.decode("utf-8")
return email.upper()

check1("as平仮平ÇÈÈ.a@yah.comÈ")
ASCEE.A@YAH.COME

def acc(a):
outputString = unidecode.unidecode(a)
return outputString.upper()

acc("as平仮平ÇÈÈ.a@yah.comÈ")
ASPING JIA PING CEE.A@YAH.COME
```

The output I am expecting for

```
acc("as平仮平ÇÈÈ.a@yah.comÈ")
```

is this
`("AS平仮平CEE.A@YAH.COME")` .

Comment: Can you add what you are expecting to get on each example please.

Comment: Where you've used `email.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`, could you use `'replace'` in place of `'ignore'`? You could then replace the resulting question marks with spaces... Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_encode.asp

Comment: Hello.The output I am expecting for acc("as平仮平ÇÈÈ.a@yah.comÈ") is this ("AS平仮平CEE.A@YAH.COME") .